# Subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ of which no $2$ are homeomorphic.

Tags: general-topology

I'm reviewing general topology and I'm having trouble with this problem:

Let $Z_0 := \{ \frac{1}{i} \mid i = 1,2, \ldots\}$, $Z_1 := Z_0 \cup \{0\}$, $I_0 := (0,1)$, $I_1 := [0,1]$. Prove that no two of the following subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$:  $Z_0 \times I_0, \quad Z_1 \times I_0, \quad Z_0 \times I_1, \quad Z_1 \times I_1$ are homeomorphic.

I don't really know how to approach this.

I believe there must be a simple proof, but all of these subsets are connected, all are path-connected and all have the property that if you remove any one of their points they stay path-connected, which is pretty much all the approaches I remember from my classes.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: $Z_0$ and $Z_1$ are not connected, so none of the products is either (since the other factor is non-empty).

Comment: Try compactness too.

Comment: thanks for your answers everyone! I just noticed while reading them that I misunderstood the question, I didn't think of cartesian products but of sums of intervals joining points $1/i$ with points of the interval $(0,1)$, cause the last problem I did was something like that ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$Z_1\times I_1$ is the only compact space in your list.

$Z_0\times I_1$ and $Z_1\times I_1$ have compact connected components, but only the first one is locally connected.

The remaining two sets do not have compact connected components and are distinguished by local connectivity as well.

Answer (score 2):

$Z_1\times I_1$ is the only compact set.

$Z_0\times I_0$ is not homeomorphic to $Z_1\times I_0$ since the later has a non-open connected component and the former does not. For the same reason $Z_1\times I_0$ is not homeomorphic to $Z_0\times I_1$.

Finally, $Z_0\times I_0$ and $Z_0\times I_1$ are not homeomorphic since the later has compact connected components, the former does not.